# call svg file - pattern not work

Tags: html, svg

I have svg file. In this file I wrote pattern

```
 <pattern id="pattern-image" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
     <image id = "mid" xlink:href="4.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></image>
 </pattern>
```

At file this works properly, when I call SVG pattern not work

```
<image xlink:href="img/p_vor_03_1.svg" width="900" height="900"/>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIz2E.png "At SVG file"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS1KA.png "At SVG file"

---

solved!
I just use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You're not closing your `</pattern>`

Comment: @bujanca-mihai, at file tag closed.

Comment: Please create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You are not providing enough information to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an SVG is referenced via an `<image>` tag it must be complete in a single file i.e. it cannot reference other external files.

You'll need to convert the `<image>` in the pattern into a [data URL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-URL) in order for the pattern to work when used via an `<image>`

Comment: can you give me an example, pls.

Comment: The link leads to examples

Comment: im using this : `<img alt="6" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RL3RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAeAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAA......">
` but it dont working

Comment: SVG files have `<image>` elements with xlink:href attributes rather. `<img>` with src is for html only.

Comment: ok. if i add data url i can't change my pattern. But i need to change it.

Comment: It's in an image, you can't change SVG in images no matter whether you use data URLs or not. They have no externally accessible DOM and are not scriptable.

Comment: can u say what i need to do?

Comment: I said what you need to do, you keep adding requirements.